# Get exacty data to send email when the cell changed?

Tags: function, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, auto

I got a functione here:

```
function approvedby() {
var approvedrange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Responses 1").getRange("E2:E500");
var approved = approvedrange.getValue();

if (approved == "A"){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Responses 1"));
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
var dataRange = s.getRange("A2:D500");
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (i in data) {
var rowData = data[i];  
var formno = rowData[1]; 
var description = rowData[2]; 
var plant = rowData[3]; 

var message = 'Form No: ' + formno + "\n\n" + 'Description: ' + description + "\n\n" + 'Plant: ' + plant + "\n\n";
var subject = "[Approved] Form"
var email = "myemail@hotmail.com";

MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);

}
}
}
```

What i want is when i change the value of Col E to "A" or "B", an email notice will be send auto to my email with the message inclue contents from Col A -> Col D but email message show the contents from Col A -> Col D same row when Col E changed only.

Example:

- When E2 changed to "A", an email will be sent with message inclue content from A2 -> D2 only
- When E3 changed to "A", an email will be sent with message inclue content from A3 -> D3 only

By now, with the script, when i changed Col E to "A", its send to my email everything from Col A to Col D, not same row exactly when Col E changed.

So, i'm noob at script and see yours help!
Thanks!

Comment: You need to create an `onEdit()` function, capture the cells value when it's edited, and run the code

Answer (score 1):

The following script will send an email with the data corresponding to the row edited in Column E (i.e only when you enter "A").

I will assume that the data are within the following columns, which you can modify If I didn't get the order correctly:

- **Form No**: Column B
- **Description**: Column C
- **Plant**: Column D

> You also need to create an Installable Trigger:

Go to your **script editor** and then to **Edit->Current Project Triggers** and the trigger pannel **Add Trigger**. Select your function (**onEdit**) and set the event type to: **on edit**.

> If you leave Column F empty, the script will also write when (date/time) the email
>   was sent.

**Code**:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var ss = e.range.getSheet();
  var range = e.range;

  if(e.source.getSheetName() == "Responses 1" && e.range.getColumn() == 5 && range.getValue()=="A"){


    var emailid= "myemail@hotmail.com";
    var subject = "[Approved] Form";
    var formno = ss.getRange('B'+ range.getRow()).getValue();
    var description = ss.getRange('C'+ range.getRow()).getValue();
    var plant = ss.getRange('D'+ range.getRow()).getValue();
    var message = "Form No: " +formno+ "\n\nDescription: "+description+ "\n\nPlant: "+plant;
    var sent = ss.getRange("F" + range.getRow());

    MailApp.sendEmail(emailid, subject, message);

    // Write in Column F when the email was sent:

    sent.setFontColor("#228B22");
    sent.setValue("Latest update: Mail sent @" + new Date());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand that:

1. If E2 or E3 or E4 etc. is changed to "A", every row from A2:D500 is being sent in email.
2. You want to send only row data for the row that has been edited. If E2 is edited, data from  A2+B2+C2+D2 should be sent in email, if E3 is edited data from A3+B3+C3+D3 should be sent in email... correct?

If my understanding is correct, please consider changing your code as below:

```
function approvedby() {
    var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1; // Number of rows to process
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4);

    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    var emailMessage = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            var row = data[i];
            emailMessage = row[0] + row[1] + row[2] + row[3]; //Concatenate the values in column A to column D of the current row
            var emailSent = row[5];  //Checks the email status of the row in column F
                if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT){
                    try{
                        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, emailMessage);
                        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
                    }
                    catch(e){
                        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(e.message);
                    }  
                 }
         }
}
```

Include an onEdit trigger to call approvedby() function.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails

Comment: In the original solution I posted, I had not mentioned this line:  "Include an onEdit trigger to call approvedby() function.". My answer was then downvoted. After I included the line the downvotes have been reversed.

Comment: The reason I did not include this line: "Include an onEdit trigger to call approvedby() function." in my original answer is because any edit to the spreadsheet will result in function approvedby() being called, not just edits made to cells in E2:E500. This could potentially make the script unstable and not user friendly, if an email is sent when it is not supposed to.

Comment: The developer then needs to work in the logic at the correct time/moment at which the mail is to be sent. Eiher through time based triggers or on user confirmation. Using the sendEmail method in onEdiit function could result in instability of the application.

Comment: Any edit will result in onEdit being called to check the status of 500 rows of data. The developer needs to decide if that is required.